# Running Deploy to Azure from SQL Sever 2016 Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Error at first step: One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package. Error SQL71564: The element User: (schema name) has property AuthenticationType set to a value that us not supported in Azure SQL Database v12

Answer (score 1):

It seems ,you are having some users configured to use windows authentication..so try dropping those users and try exporting as bacpac again...

Instead of using SSMS export to bacpac option..You can use DACPAC (Bacpac+data)

below is the total syntax..

> .\SqlPackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:SourceSQLServer /SourceDatabaseName:SourceDB
>
> /TargetFile:”C:\Temp\DBMigration\SourceDB.dacpac” /p:ExtractAllTableData=true
>
> /p:ExtractReferencedServerScopedElements=false /p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=true

Last two parameters are optional,but changing userloginmappings property to false will help you

**References:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dfurman/2015/03/25/database-migration-to-sql-azure-using-a-bacpac-a-blocker-and-a-workaround/

Comment: thanks - that's it - a user with the same name as the database schema - if it was a user called anything else, I think I would have worked it out. thanks for the tip